# Drop Elements from Pandas Series by Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series df (dates = index):

```
2015-09-10     58
2015-09-11     40
2015-09-12     33
2015-09-13     42
2015-09-14     22
2015-09-15     88
2015-09-16     99
2015-09-17    124
```

I'd like to drop the dates from 2015-09-11 to 2015-09-15, so my df would look like:

```
2015-09-10     58
2015-09-16     99
2015-09-17    124
```

I've tried using df.drop["2015-09-11":"2015-09-15"], but i get an error:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any advices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try that:

```
s = pd.Series([58,40,33,42,22,88,99,124], index =["2015-09-10","2015-09-11","2015-09-12","2015-09-13","2015-09-14","2015-09-15","2015-09-16","2015-09-17"])

In [140]: s
Out[140]:
2015-09-10     58
2015-09-11     40
2015-09-12     33
2015-09-13     42
2015-09-14     22
2015-09-15     88
2015-09-16     99
2015-09-17    124
dtype: int64

s.drop(s["2015-09-11":"2015-09-15"].index)

In [142]: s.drop(s["2015-09-11":"2015-09-15"].index)
Out[142]:
2015-09-10     58
2015-09-16     99
2015-09-17    124
dtype: int64
```