# Pandas drop elements from column by string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do something really simple, but I couldn't find a solution, yet:

Given a dataframe df I am trying to select a column (with strings) and drop items that are named "x".

I have found questions about removing by index
([Drop Elements from Pandas Series by Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066533/drop-elements-from-pandas-series-by-index)) but not by their content.

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'Aaba', 'Baca', np.nan, 'CABA', 'dog', 'cat'])
```

Trying to remove:

```
s.drop('A')
s.drop(s['A'])
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Thanks for finding the other questions! I saw the first one (filter a Series), but I couldn't really abstract the way how to do that with strings (my bad, new to python). I think the second one (Select rows...) is not a duplicate, since it is about selection only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a series as you have, try just indexing like this:

```
s.loc[s!='A']
```

For a dataframe with named columns, try:

```
s.loc[s['column_name'] != 'A']
```

Comment: `s.loc[s!='A']` did the trick! Thank you for the super-fast reply!