# How to drop elements from a series by using a Pandas for loop index as the index parameter for the drop function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to run a loop that filters certain elements based on a condition and removes those that match, as shown below:

```
for index, value in enumerate(some_dataset.iloc):
if min(some_dataset.iloc[index]) >= some_dataset.iloc[0].values[index]:
    dataset_filtered = some_dataset.drop(index=index)
```

However, the value being passed to the index parameter in the variable `index` does not seem to behave as an integer. Instead, I receive the following error for the first value that attempts to be dropped:

> KeyError: '[1] not found in axis'

Thinking it was a Series element, I attempted to cast it as an integer by setting `index = index.astype(int)` in the parameters for the drop() function, but in this case, it *does* seem to behave as an integer, producing the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'

To solve this problem, I looked at Anton Protopopov's answer to [this question asked by jjjayn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066533/drop-elements-from-pandas-series-by-index), but it did not help in my situation as specific elements were referenced in place of an iterating index.

---

For context, the if statement is in place to filter out any samples whose lowest values are at the 0th index (thus, where the `min()` value of a sample transect is equal to the value at index 0. Essentially, it would tell me that values in the sample only grow larger for increasing `x`, which here is wavelength. When I print a table to see which samples this applies to, the results are what I expect (100 nm wavelengths are the 0th index):

```
Sample     Value (100 nm)  Value (minima)  Min (λ)   

#2         0.0050          0.0050          100          

#3         0.0060          0.0060          100          

#14        0.0025          0.0025          100

...
```

So, with these results printed, I don't think the condition is the issue. Indeed, the first index that should be getting dropped is also one that I'd expect to be dropped -- sample 2, which corresponds to [1], is getting passed, but I think the brackets are being passed along with it (at least, that's my guess). So in sum, the issue is that a single-element list/series `[n]` is being passed to the index parameter instead of the integer, `n`, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Answer fully rewritten due to new information. See diff for previous versions.

---

I reproduced your error. I had initially thought it was something related to an indexing error, which the following code would have forced to occur.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0, 3)})
for i, r in enumerate(df.iloc):
    print(i, type(r), df.iloc[0].values[i])
```

This code will throw an `IndexError`, complaining that the value in `i` is greater than the number of columns present. But the error that you report, a `KeyError`, only occurs if you try something like this:

```
>>> df.drop(index=15)
KeyError: '[15] not found in axis'
```

The reason for this is because when you drop with the index keyword, it is not dropping based on your `iloc` indexer (ie `0 ... n`) but rather on the standard `loc` indexer, which can be in arbitrary order and have missing values etc. The underlying reason for why the integer `15` is turned into `[15]` is because it is automatically wrapped into a list by the error print line: `raise KeyError(f'{ list(labels[mask]) } not found in axis')`.

Use only one form of indexer. In this instance, I would use `for i, row in df.iterrows()` rather than enumerating over the `df.iloc` property.

Comment: Thank you for the response! `some_dataset.iloc[0].values[index]` isn't a mistake (at least, I don't think it is) -- I am trying to filter out any samples whose lowest values are at the 0th index. When I print a table to see which samples this apply to, the results are what I expect. So, I don't think the condition is the issue. Indeed, the first index that should be getting dropped is also one that I'd expect to be dropped -- but `[n]` is being passed to index instead of an integer, `n`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you're trying to do and a short example of it?

Comment: Absolutely! I've added it now.

Comment: @ttoshiro Major changes to my answer. It relates again to indexing. Check `set(range(0, len(some_dataset)) == set(some_dataset.index.values)`.